# valgrind "Invalid write of size 8"

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, memory, valgrind

I'm running a multi-threaded Qt application in C++, Ubuntu 14.04, and getting an "Invalid write of size 8" error with valgrind that I don't understand.

Here's my code:

```
// Allocate memory for arrays
deltas = new double[time_count]; // (time_count is 794)
```

Then, I create a bunch of threads, which assign values into the `deltas` array:

```
cout << "time_index = " << time_index << endl;
deltas[time_idx] = calculated_value;
```

When I run it, the highest time_index printed is 793, as expected:

```
time_index =  793
```

Yet, for some reason, valgrind gives me the following error:

`==16575== Thread 21 Thread (pooled):
==16575== Invalid write of size 8
==16575==    at 0x421508: TimeIndicator::calculate_delta(int) (algorithms.cpp:1030)
...
==16575==  Address 0x107ba860 is 0 bytes after a block of size 6,352 alloc'd`

Valgrind seems to think I'm writing past the edge of the array, yet according to the printout, I never exceed 793, which is array_size - 1.

Comment: You use `time_idx` in the array expression, not `time_index`. Or is it just a typo?

Comment: @errikos You're right! Stupid mistake in my code. I had a 'time_idx' and a 'time_index' and I got them confused... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Errikos pointed out, I was used "time_idx" instead of "time_index". A lot of grief from a simple mistake.

Comment: This method always works: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging :-)